# If I use the wilcox.test from R for paired data, what exactly it returns? I want to compute the effect size based on that

Tags: effect-size, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I want to calculate effect size for the paired Wilcoxon (signed rank).

There are two options: Z/sqrt(N_pairs)
or the rank-biserial correlation.

The wilcox.test(... paired=TRUE) returns "V".

There's so many letters in the literature: for Mann-Whitney (unpaired) it's either "U" or "W" (depending on approach, i.e. the Wilcoxon approach), for paired Wilcoxon it's Z or V.

In my case V = 0.

Data:

```
d <- structure(list(PatientId = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
    "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), Timepoint = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Baseline", "Month 3"
    ), class = "factor"), Result = c(0, 9, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -24L), class = "data.frame")

> wilcox.test(Result ~ Timepoint, paired = TRUE, data = d)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  Result by Timepoint
V = 0, p-value = 0.1
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning messages:
1: In wilcox.test.default(x = c(0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 7),  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(x = c(0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 7),  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

The rank_biserial doesn't work:

```
> rank_biserial(Result ~ Timepoint, paired = TRUE, data = d)
r (rank biserial) |         95% CI
----------------------------------
-1.00             | [-1.00, -1.00]
Warning message:
In ranktransform.numeric((x - y) - mu, sign = TRUE, verbose = verbose) :
  Zeros detected. These cannot be sign-rank transformed.
```

But the rstatix package implementation returns something else (matching wilcox.test without continuity correction):

```
coin::wilcoxsign_test(Result ~ Timepoint | PatientId, data=d, zero.method = "Wilcoxon")

    Asymptotic Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test

data:  y by x (pos, neg) 
     stratified by block
Z = -2, p-value = 0.07
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0

> wilcox.test(Result ~ Timepoint, paired = TRUE, data = d, correct = FALSE)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  Result by Timepoint
V = 0, p-value = 0.07
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning messages:
1: In wilcox.test.default(x = c(0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 7),  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(x = c(0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 7),  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

So is the "V" connected with "Z"?

In this case, I can calculate the effect size using the Z/sqrt(12) = 0.577, which is moderate-to-large (according to Cohen).

So, is there any chance to get the Z (and calculate the effect size) directly from R base wilcox.test? I would like to stick to the base library.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it. To convert the V to Z: Zstat<-qnorm(result$p.value/2)

```
> result <- wilcox.test(Result ~ Timepoint, paired = TRUE, data = d, correct = TRUE)

> Zstat<-qnorm(result$p.value/2) 
> 
> Zstat
[1] -1.66
> 
> Zstat / sqrt(12)
[1] -0.478
```

If the correction is skipped, then the result agrees with the previous I cited:

```
> result <- wilcox.test(Result ~ Timepoint, paired = TRUE, data = d, correct = FALSE)
Warning messages:
1: In wilcox.test.default(x = c(0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 7),  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(x = c(0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 7),  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
> Zstat<-qnorm(result$p.value/2) 
> 
> Zstat / sqrt(12)
[1] -0.531
```